# Is it good or bad to have dynamic content in page titles and/or description

Tags: seo, content, title, meta-description, dynamic

In a local listing website, I append number of search results found in the description(not in title currntly) meta tag of the page as I think this is valuable for users

for e.g. "Find address, phone numbers, blah blah blah for `21` outlets in `locality`. some more stuff after this..."

as more places are added to the database, the description for the `same page` will change frequently. is this good or bad for SEO

how about doing the same for title tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be an idea to simply put: 'Find Address in `locality` and leave out the number of results from the page title and description. No one will be searching '21 addresses in locality' but they might put 'find addresses in locality'.

Comment: Also, it depends on how fast you grow compared to how often the search engines crawl and update your pages - if you're indexed when you've got 21 listings, and now have 200, but the search engine still says "21 listings" that's not going to entice people to come and visit your site.